# Field should not exceed 4 characters and characters should be unique

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have a textbox where i will be entering values into textbox, my regular expression should validate for

It should allow 4 characters should not exceeding more than that, it should not allow numbers and special characters , and my characters should not be duplicate for example it should allow ABCD , and should not allow AABD or ABCB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
^(?:([a-z])(?!.*\1)){1,4}$
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ufdn)

I used the modifier `i` (IgnoreCase). You can add to the character class `[a-z]` any character you want to allow.

Each character is matched by `([a-z])` stored in the capture group 1. The negative lookahead `(?!.*\1))` checks for every character if it is repeated somewhere else in the string.

`{1,4}` allows from 1 to 4 characters. I am not completely sure about your spec here, if you want to have exactly 4 then change it to `{4}`